# fetch logs for an application in RStudio Connect?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-connect

Is there a way to pulls the jobs from the logs in RStudio Connect? I know that we can go to the application, click on each job under the logs and look for info but is there a way I can pull all the logs as an API or anything? I am trying to pull the logs, tweak them and display in another app for some users.

TIA

Comment: you could try `showLogs()` function in {rsconnect} package: [https://rstudio.github.io/rsconnect/reference/showLogs.html]

Comment: @josepmariaporrà I get the following error Error: HTTP 401
GET https: //api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/?filter=account_id:66&filter=name:'nameofapp'&count=100&offset=0
invalid token.
Why am I getting the api.shinyapps.io though I am using the rsconnect package?

Comment: I guess you have first to check that you can access first RStudio Connect content: [https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/user/api-keys/]